# Android R Emulator not showing Navbar and Status bar in VS Code Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, navbar, statusbar

I am using Visual Studio Code to code in Flutter, but when I start the emulator, it doesn't show the navbar and status bar, it was showing both of these before, but then after some time when I again started the emulator, it stopped showing the navbar and status bar.

[image: Navbar and Status bar not showing in emulator]

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the device from the AVD device manager and then again reinstalling it with the same Android R version, then both the status bar and navigation bar came back. So it worked for me!

[image]